# How to correctly make rails override foreign_key naming in belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, associations, legacy-database

I am sure this is a very basic question, and I have seen related ones but I'm still confused. I am very inexperienced with RoR - please excuse my ignorance!

I've set up mvc classes using scaffolding on a legacy database (via [schema_to_scaffold](https://github.com/frenesim/schema_to_scaffold)). When I open schema.rb I can see that the primary keys have been correctly identified with their non-default names, e.g.:

```
 create_table "my_ncs", primary_key: "ID_NC", force: true do |m| 
  
   # etc...

 end

 create_table "my_revisions", primary_key: "ID_REVISION", force: true do |m|
   m.decimal "ID_NC", precision: 10, scale:0, null: false 

   # etc ...
 
 end
```

There is a one-to-many relationship between one `"my_nc"` and the associated `"my_revisions"`.
(The first thing that confuses me is that the corresponding model files `MyNc` and `MyRevision` do not show what I expected: `self.primary_key='ID_NC'` and `self.primary_key='ID_REVISION'` but never mind)

Now I'm trying to set up this association and nested routing to be able to have a url like say `/my_ncs/6/my_revisions` give me all the `my_revisions` for the `my_nc` with `ID_NC=6`.

This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
class MyNc < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :MyRevisions
end

class MyRevision < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :MyNc, foreign_key: 'ID_NC'
end
```

Now I am trying to use the `rails console` to test this, and **this is when I get totally confused**:

```
irb(main):001:0> n = MyNc.find(6)
  MyNc Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  `my_ncs`.* FROM `my_ncs`  WHERE `my_ncs`.`ID_NC` = 6 LIMIT 1
=> #<MyNc ID_NC: 6, etc...>

irb(main):002:0> n.MyRevisions
  MyRevision Load (22.0ms)  SELECT `my_revisions`.* FROM `my_revisions`  WHERE `my_revisions`.`my_nc_
id` = 6
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'my_revisions.my_nc_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `my_revisions`.* FROM `my
_revisions`  WHERE `my_revisions`.`my_nc_id` = 6
```

The default name `my_nc_id` for the foreign_key is used, instead of `ID_NC`.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Please use Ruby naming conventions!

Comment: Other newbies like me please read on @marek-lipka 's answer to understand BroiSatse's comment :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should also specify `foreign_key` in `has_many` association:

```
class MyNc < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :my_revisions, foreign_key: 'ID_NC'
end
class MyRevision < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :my_nc, foreign_key: 'ID_NC'
end
```

note that I changed your association names to make them follow Ruby conventions.